# arm-gcc compiled code is bigger than on armclang

Tags: gcc, stm32, compiler-optimization, stm32cubemx, armclang

I've generated the same project on STM32CubeMx and added the same code

- `uint8_t* data = new uint8_t[16]`
- `HAL_Delay` and `HAL_GPIO_TogglePin` in infinite loop

for the `Keil MDK` project and as `Makefile` project. In both `main.c` is changed to `main.cpp`

The whole user code looks like:

```cpp
    uint8_t* data;
    
    int main(void)
    {
      HAL_Init();
      SystemClock_Config();
      MX_GPIO_Init();
      MX_USART3_UART_Init();
      MX_USB_OTG_FS_PCD_Init();
    
      data = new uint8_t[16];
      for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)data[i] = i+1;
      
      while (1)
      {
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD3_GPIO_Port, GPIO_PIN_14);
        HAL_Delay(500);
      }
    }
```

In Keil I use `armclang v6.19` and in Makefile project I use `arm-none-eabi-gcc v12.2.1 20221205`

I've checked compilation results with different optimization flags and here are results:

- O0

Keil:

```
Program Size: Code=11950 RO-data=510 RW-data=12 ZI-data=3012
```

arm-gcc:

```
 text    data     bss     dec     hex 
 17572     100    3268   20940    51cc
```

- O3

Keil:

```
Program Size: Code=8238 RO-data=510 RW-data=12 ZI-data=3012
```

arm-gcc:

```
 text    data     bss     dec     hex
 12448     100    3268   15816    3dc8
```

- Oz

Keil:

```
Program Size: Code=6822 RO-data=510 RW-data=12 ZI-data=3012
```

arm-gcc:

```
 text    data     bss     dec     hex
 11876     100    3268   15244    3b8c
```

What is the reason of such a difference? How can I fix that?

I guess, there are differences in -O* flag meanings in theese compilers and they use different optimizer options, but I am not sure

Comment: Do you assume, that different compilers should generate the same code, from the same source? There is even a difference between two versions of the same compiler. Optimization options are going far beyond -Ox flags, in GCC look for Link Time Optimization, `-flto` flag.

Comment: What target options do you use?  Is ARM GCC using any `-mcpu=` option (like `-mcpu=cortex-m3`), or is it defaulting to `-marm` 4-byte instructions?  (Actual STM32 boards have Cortex-M CPUs which only support Thumb mode, but stm32cubemx mentions being able to target Cortex-A cores as well.)  Are you making a Linux executable with CRT startup code?  What C++ library did you link?  There must be one since you're using `new`, presumably just to pull in part of the C++ library instead of just statically allocating 16 bytes.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Which GCC optimization flags affect binary size the most?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72030595) but you've already tried `-Oz`.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two completely different build toolchains so the result will always differ.

## Keil

Uses the proprietary `armclang` to compile and `armlink` to link. `armclang` is a fork of `clang` for which you can see the optimization options [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html#code-generation-options) but Arm has it's own documentation for that [here](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101754/0619/armclang-Reference/armclang-Command-line-Options/-O--armclang-) because it adds some proprietary magic sauce on top.

## Arm GCC

Uses the GNU compiler collection as basis for which you can find the documentation for optimization levels [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html). There are no 2 documentations for that because Arm actively contributes to the Arm GCC.