# SSE instruction MOVSD (extended: floating point scalar & vector operations on x86, x86-64)

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, sse, sse2

I am somehow confused by the MOVSD assembly instruction. I wrote some numerical code computing some matrix multiplication, simply using ordinary C code with no SSE intrinsics. I do not even include the header file for SSE2 intrinsics  for compilation. But when I check the assembler output, I see that:

1) 128-bit vector registers XMM are used;
2) SSE2 instruction MOVSD is invoked.

I understand that MOVSD essentially operates on single double precision floating point. It only uses the lower 64-bit of an XMM register and set the upper 64-bit 0. But I just don't understand two things:

1) I never give the compiler any hint for using SSE2. Plus, I am using GCC not intel compiler. As far as I know, intel compiler will automatically seek opportunities for vectorization, but GCC will not. So how does GCC know to use MOVSD?? Or, has this x86 instruction been around long before SSE instruction set, and the _mm_load_sd() intrinsics in SSE2 is just to provide backward compatibility for using XMM registers for scalar computation?

2) Why does not the compiler use other floating point registers, either the 80-bit floating point stack, or 64-bit floating point registers?? Why must it take the toll using XMM register (by setting upper 64-bit 0 and essentially wasting that storage)? Does XMM do provide faster access??

---

By the way, I have another question regarding SSE2. I just can't see the difference between _mm_store_sd() and _mm_storel_sd(). Both store the lower 64-bit value to an address. What is the difference? Performance difference?? Alignment difference??

Thank you.

---

**Update 1:**

OKAY, obviously when I first asked this question, I lacked some basic knowledge on how a CPU manages floating point operations. So experts tend to think my question is non-sense. Since I did not include even the shortest sample C code, people might think this question vague as well. Here I would provide [a review](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36121889/4891738) as an answer, which hopefully will be useful to any people unclear about the floating point operations on modern CPUs.

Comment: In 64 bit mode the calling convention already mandates SSE registers for floating point arguments and return values. Since the SSE registers are not organized as a stack, and there are more of them, it's easier for the compiler to utilize. There are scalar SSE instructions. Also, it's funny you are concerned about wasting half of the space in them - if you don't use them at all, *all* of them go to waste ;)

Comment: There are no 64-bit floating pointer registers. There's just the 80-bit floating point stack and the XMM registers. The MOVSD instruction is a scalar instruction, not a vector instruction so its use doesn't imply automatic vectorization.

Comment: Those aren't floating point registers.

Comment: The `_pd` stores 2 doubles (128 bits) but the `_sd` only 1 double (64 bits).

Comment: Because using a general purpose register to store a floating-point value means that compiler would have to generate additional instructions to move the value into a floating point register (either the 80-bit floating point stack or an XMM register) before performing a floating point operation on that value.

Comment: No idea what you are asking. You have asked it 3 times with 3 different sets of names...

Comment: Okay, `_mm_storel_pd` generates `MOVLPD` instruction, while `_mm_store_sd` produces `MOVSD`. When writing to memory, they have equivalent functionality. At least I can't spot the difference.

Comment: @Jester: AFAICT, the only reason `movlpd` and `movsd` both exist is consistency/regularity of the encodings: `movlps` is different from `movss`, so both those instructions already existed.  SSE2 uses the same opcode with different escape bytes for the `double` instead of `single` version.  (`movlpd` is already just a waste of instruction bytes compared to `movlps` on every CPU, since AFAIK no CPUs care about single vs. double versions of any data-movement insns.  Intel has persistently kept that option open by always making single vs. double versions, up until `vextractf128` and stuff)

Comment: I don't think your question should have been down-voted just because of your ignorance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A review of floating point scalar/vector processing on modern CPUs**

The idea of vector processing dates back to old time [vector processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_processor), but these processors had been superseded by modern architectures with cache systems. So we focus on modern CPUs, especially [x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) and [x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64). These architectures are the [main stream in high performance scientific computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOP500#Architecture_and_operating_systems).

Since i386, Intel introduced the floating point stack where floating point numbers up to 80-bit wide can be held. This stack is commonly known as [x87 or 387 floating point "registers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X87), with a set of [x87 FPU instructions](http://home.agh.edu.pl/~amrozek/x87.pdf). x87 stack are not real, directly addressable registers like general purpose registers, as they are on a stack. Access to register st(i) is by offsetting the stack top register %st(0) or simply %st. With help of an instruction FXCH which swaps the contents between current stack top %st and some offset register %st(i), random access can be achieved. But FXCH can impose some performance penalty, though minimized. x87 stack provides high precision computation by calculating intermediate results with 80 bits of precision by default, to minimise roundoff error in numerically unstable algorithms. However, x87 instructions are completely scalar.

The first effort on vectorization is the [MMX instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMX_%28instruction_set%29), which implemented **integer** vector operations. The vector registers under MMX are 64-bit wide registers MMX0, MMX1, ..., MMX7. Each can be used to hold either 64-bit integers, or multiple smaller integers in a "packed" format. A single instruction can then be applied to two 32-bit integers, four 16-bit integers, or eight 8-bit integers at once. So now there are the legacy general purpose registers for scalar integer operations, as well as new MMX for integer vector operations with no shared execution resources. But MMX shared execution resources with scalar x87 FPU operation: each MMX register corresponded to the lower 64 bits of an x87 register, and the upper 16 bits of the x87 registers is unused. These MMX registers were each directly addressable. But the aliasing made it difficult to work with floating point and integer vector operations in the same application. To maximize performance, programmers often used the processor exclusively in one mode or the other, deferring the relatively slow switch between them as long as possible.

Later, [SSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) created a separate set of 128-bit wide registers XMM0–XMM7 along side of x87 stack. SSE instructions focused **exclusively** on single-precision floating-point operations (32-bit); integer vector operations were still performed using the MMX register and MMX instruction set. But now both operations can proceed at the same time, as they share no execution resources. **It is important to know that SSE not only do floating point vector operations, but also floating point scalar operations. Essentially it provides a new place where floating operations take place, and the x87 stack is no longer prior choice to carry out floating operations. Using XMM registers for scalar floating point operations is faster than using x87 stack, as all XMM registers are easier to access, while the x87 stack can't be randomly accessed without FXCH.** When I posted my question, I was clearly unaware of this fact. The other concept I was not clear about is that general purpose registers are integer/address registers. Even if they are 64-bit on x86-64, they can not hold 64-bit floating point. The main reason is that the execution unit associated with general purpose registers is ALU (arithmetic & logical unit), which is not for floating point computation.

[SSE2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2) is a major progress, as it extends vector data type, so SSE2 instructions, either scalar or vector, can work with all C standard data type. Such extension in fact makes MMX obsolete. Also, x87 stack is no long as important as it once was. Since there are two alternative places where floating point operations can take place, you can specify your option to the compiler. For example for GCC, compilation with flag

```
-mfpmath=387
```

will schedule floating point operations on the legacy x87 stack. **Note that this seems to be the default for 32-bit x86, even if SSE is already available.** For example, I have an Intel Core2Duo laptop made in 2007, and it was already equipped with SSE release up to version SSE4, while GCC will still by default use x87 stack, which makes scientific computations unnecessarily slower. In this case, we need compile with flag

```
-mfpmath=sse
```

and GCC will schedule floating point operations on XMM registers. 64-bit x86-64 user needs not worry about such configuration as this is default on x86-64. Such signal will only affect scalar floating point operation. If we have written code using vector instructions and compiler the code with flag

```
-msse2
```

then XMM registers will be the only place where computation can take place. In other words, this flags turns on -mfpmath=sse. For more information see [GCC's configuration of x86, x86-64](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.3/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html). For examples of writing SSE2 C code, see my other post [How to ask GCC to completely unroll this loop (i.e., peel this loop)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110591/how-to-ask-gcc-to-completely-unroll-this-loop-i-e-peel-this-loop).

SSE set of instructions, though very useful, are not the latest vector extensions. The AVX, [advanced vector extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions) enhances SSE by providing 3-operands and 4 operands instructions. See [number of operands in instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set#Number_of_operands) if you are unclear of what this means. 3-operands instruction optimizes the commonly seen [fused multiply-add (FMA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation) operation in scientific computing by 1) using 1 fewer register; 2) reducing the explicit amount of data movement between registers; 3) speeding up FMA computations in itself. For example of using AVX, see [@Nominal Animal's answer to my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36114098/4891738).

Comment: gcc targeting 32bit x86 defaults to making code that can run on any x86 CPU as far back as i686 (PPro).  Use `-march=native` if you want it to target the current host's instruction-set extensions.  Also, the 32bit ABI is defined to return FP args on the x87 stack.  See the [x86 tag wiki info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for ABI docs.

Comment: Most 3-operand AVX instructions just have a separate destination that isn't one of the sources.  FMA is the major exception: it still does destroy one of its operands, like an SSE instruction.  (Intel changed their mind at the last minute from FMA4 to FMA3, but didn't tell AMD, so AMD Bulldozer supports 4-operand FMA4 but not Intel-style FMA3).  Also, SSE has a some 3-operand instruction: `pblendvb` uses `xmm0` as an implicit 4th operand.  So Intel could have implemented FMA without AVX, and FMA is a bad example of how AVX reduces the need for `mov` instructions.

Comment: Other than that, this answer appears correct from my quick skim over most of it.  IDK how useful it will be to other beginners, since it looks a bit long and rambling.  IIRC, a lot of the history of x86 insn set extensions is already in the [SSE tag wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info), which I tidied up several months ago.

Comment: I didn't find out that the tag-wiki pages often had good links for a long time, either.  It's not a well-advertised feature that the site itself points out to people, so I usually link to the x86 tag wiki on almost every newbie question I comment on or answer.  re: `load1_pd`: With SSE3, the [broadcast-load only takes a single instruction (`movddup`)](https://goo.gl/8JmuCM), which is as cheap as a regular load on Nehalem and later.  On Core2, that insn also uses the ALU, and can't micro-fuse.  See the code on godbolt: without SSE3, it's a load & shuffle separately, thus slower even on Skylake.

Comment: ok.  It looks like you're mixing up 3-operand AVX instructions in general with stuff that's specific to FMA.  re: `load1_sse3`: of course you didn't find it in the intrinsics guide: it's a function I wrote to demonstrate how `_mm_load1_pd` compiled with `-msse3`.  There's no reason to change your code from using `_mm_load1_pd` to `_mm_loaddup_pd` intrinsics unless you want to make sure you get a compile error if you try to compile it without `-msse3`.  That's what my godbolt link was demonstrating.  (use backticks to get code-formatting in comments, not single quotes).

Comment: Right, don't use the composite intrinsics unless there's no way to do what you need with one instruction.  Just use `_mm_load1_pd`.  As my godbolt link proves, it compiles to ideal code (`movddup`) with `-msse3`.  It's a good idea to have a look over the asm output for important loops, to make sure the compiler didn't make a mess.