# Optimal way to store double SSE2/AVX/AVX512 as floats using intrinsics

Tags: vectorization, avx, sse2, avx512

I often need to use double for accuracy reasons, but I want to store the results as floats. What is the optimal way? I'm current using:

SSE2: `_mm_store_sd((double*)dst, _mm_castps_pd(_mm_cvtpd_ps(xmm)));`

AVX: `_mm_storeu_ps(dst, _mm256_cvtpd_ps(ymm));`

AVX512: `_mm256_storeu_ps(dst, _mm512_cvtpd_ps(zmm));`

Any improvement ideas?

Comment: I think your code is ok. You can use `_mm_storel_pd` or `_mm_storel_pi ` instead of `_mm_store_sd`. On Intel Skylake that would be as fast as your solution, according to Agner Fogs instruction tables. Maybe there is a small difference on some older architectures, but I didn't check.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: See also Peter Cordes' comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36048502/sse-instruction-movsd-extended-floating-point-scalar-vector-operations-on-x8#comment59749434_36048502).

Comment: The number of instruction bytes might differ between the different instructions, which may have a very minor impact on the performance in some cases. See also this [Godbolt link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9GvSX2). In principle the compiler should choose the best instruction. However, Clang prefers `movlps`, while GCC prefers `movlpd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conversion from packed-double to packed-float is only available in narrowing form, not in a version that takes 2 vectors of double and packs into 1 vector of float.  So yes, the intrinsics for [`[v]cvtpd2ps`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTPD2PS.html) are your only option.  These instructions decode to 2 uops on modern Intel; one for the FMA port(s) and one for the shuffle port.  (https://agner.org/optimize/)

Storing the result is straightforward, some form of `_mm_store/storeu` is what you want.

---

For 128-bit vectors (resulting in 2x `float` = 64 bits), you don't have a whole 128-bit vector of results.  You could shuffle two together into a 128-bit vector, but with an FP shuffle throughput of 1 per clock on Intel since Sandybridge, it's probably best to just store them both separately.

You want `movlps` instead of `movsd` to store the low 64 bits of a `float` vector;  It saves one instruction byte, and the C intrinsic takes less casting to use.  But unfortunately it takes a `__m64*` instead of a `float*`, so you do still need one cast:

```
_mm_storel_pi((__m64*)dst,   _mm_cvtpd_ps(xmm) );
```

But for loading, you definitely do want `movsd` to avoid a false dependency on the old value.  `movlps` loads merge into a register; `movsd` loads zero-extend.  Actually, `cvtps2pd xmm, qword [mem]` takes care of that for you, if you can get the compiler to emit that from intrinsics.

It might be hard to do it safely, for similar reasons to `pmovzxbw xmm, qword [mem]`: compilers fail to fold a qword load into a memory operand for pmovzx/sx: ([Loading 8 chars from memory into an __m256 variable as packed single precision floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279513/loading-8-chars-from-memory-into-an-m256-variable-as-packed-single-precision-f))